Selenium Adding Default Profile
I want my Google Chrome browser, which I opened for web scraping, to open with either the default profile or a specific profile. Selenium automatically opens it as a guest. I tried this code but it didn't work. How can I solve this problem?
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


#options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\burak\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Person 1")
#options.add_argument("profile-directory={profile}")

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\burak\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Person 1') 
options.add_argument('profile-directory=Default')
service = Service(r"C:\\Users\\burak\\OneDrive\\Masaüstü\\Python\\Scrap\\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')


dir is a built in function in python.

you have to format your code - don't split line to new row - because now it looks like dir is new variable but it is part of previous line.

what measn "didn't work"? Do you get error message? If so then show it in question (not in comments) as text (not image). We can't run it, we can't see your computer, and we can't read in your mind - you have to describe all details in question (not in comments)
